# android: what's the difference between a timertask and a service?

Tags: android

I'm using a timertask in the main activity in order to update some data repeatedly every X seconds.

This data is of static form, so it's a public static method

is this a bad technique? I mean, using static methods like this

I know there's this thing called Service, but there aren't really many examples online on how to use it in order to update every X seconds a variable that should be then accessed by some activity

so my question is, what's the difference between using a timer task and a service? is a timertask just a time counter and nothing else? does it run in parallel if it's being used with a handler or not? and what happens if you have something like this:

```
       handler = new Handler();
    t = new Timer();
    task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                                         //do stuff;

                }
            });

        }

    };
    t.schedule(task, 0, 10000);
```

how exactly does this code work? what does it do? does it run in parallel? why even if I leave the activity where this code is first being called, it still runs? what makes it run in this case?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) is part of standard Java and can be use for delayed or repeated execution for some piece of (Runnable) code. It's use is [discouraged on Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html). You can use a Handler instead.

A Service can be used as a independent and UI-less part of your Android application. It can run and create it's own threads and can be started for UI or with Intents through a AlarmManager for example.

It think want you want is a Service which creates it's own thread and does some work. When the work is done, memory will be freed on Android when the garbage collector kicks in, something you do not control and that's a good thing.